# How to fix fonts bug in Julia?

Tags: fonts, windows-10, julia

I ran Julia and got

[image]

As you see, there are garbage characters after `search:`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with Julia but with the font your terminal emulator uses.

It seems you are on Windows. In this case two things can be recommended (this is not an exhaustive list, but the basic options):

- use terminal emulator built in into [Juno](https://junolab.org/)
- install [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) and then set font to [Unifont](http://www.unifoundry.com/pub/unifont/unifont-12.1.02/font-builds/unifont-12.1.02.ttf) with disabled "Alternative font"

Here is an example screenshot from ConEmu with font size 16 and width 9:
[image]